# Java - Finding Largest and Smallest Numbers using an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am supposed to make a program that takes 10 numbers from a user input, find the largest and smallest number and display all the inputs from the user. This program does use an array. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses Scanner
public class ArrayTester {
    // begin execution
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare and create array object
        // declare smallest and largest int variables 
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[10];
        int smallest = numbers[0], largest = numbers[0];

        // create Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // prompt user 
        System.out.print("Please enter 10 numbers: \n");
        // use for loop to obtain user input
        for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
            numbers[counter] = input.nextInt();
        } // end obtaining input

        // enhanced for loop to find largest and smallest values
        for (int i : numbers) {
            if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = numbers[i];
            } // end finding smallest
            else if (numbers[i] > largest) {
                largest = numbers[i];
            } // end finding largest number 
        } // end finding largest and smallest values

        // for loop to print user input 
        System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Input");
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= numbers.length; counter++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, numbers[counter]);
        } // end printing input values

        // print smallest and largest numbers
        System.out.printf("Smallest number: %d\nLargest number: %d\n", smallest, largest);
        System.out.print("Programmed by Christian Lapinig");
    } // end main
 } // end ArrayTester
```

At this point I am able to obtain user inputs, but I run into this problem:

```
Please enter 10 numbers: 
454
392
33
41
6
44
39
21
12
2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 454
at ArrayTester.main(ArrayTester.java:32)
```

Would I need a try and catch block to fix this?

Comment: You've misunderstood how a `for each` loop works. When you write `for (int i : numbers)`, `i` is not the index, it's the actual number in the array.

Comment: try catch block wont solve the error. it will just ahndle the error in an elegant way. can u highlight which line is line 32 ??

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan Here is line 32: if (numbers[i] < smallest)

Comment: seee the first comment from pbabcdefp and /or my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `try-catch` would just swallow the exception.  Your problem is that the enhanced for loop is iterating over the *values* of the array, but you're treating it like it's the index, so you check `numbers[454]` and immediately blow up because you're outside the length of the array.

Either iterate over the indexes, or just work with the values directly:

```
for (int i : numbers) {
    if (i < smallest) {
        smallest = i;
    } // end finding smallest
    else if (i > largest) {
        largest = i;
    } // end finding largest number 
} // end finding largest and smallest values
```

Comment: This worked! But it when I ran it in terminal again it gave the correct value for largest number, but 0 for smallest even though my smallest input was 2?

Comment: You're initializing the values for `smallest` and `largest` to the first element in your array before you've added the values to it, so they're both set to the array's initial values of 0. None of the values are smaller than 0, so `smallest` remains 0. You have values larger than that, so `largest` works. Initialize your `smallest` value to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and I think you'll find it finds the right value.  (And you can initialize your `largest` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the way you use the for-loop as already stated in the other answers. A shorter approach in Java 8 though, would be using a stream:

`IntStream.of(numbers).max()` and `IntStream.of(numbers).min()`

Comment: With the obvious disadvantage of iterating over the array twice.

Comment: @BrettOkken Does't really matter with 10 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= numbers.length; counter++)
```

You put `=<`, instead you should put `<`. if counter equals to length, it tries to reach out of range because indexes start from zero.

Comment: He will have 10 + 1 elements then

Answer (score 0):

CHange

```
for (int i : numbers) {
```

to

```
for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this loop:

```
for (int i : numbers) {
```

This loop means iterates over the elements of the array, not its indexes. So, you can say:

```
for (int a : numbers) {
   if(a > ...) {
   ....
}
```

Alternatively you can use array index like the following"

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.lenth; i++) {
   if(numbers[i] > ...) {
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
for (int i=0 ;i< numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = numbers[i];
            } // end finding smallest
            else if (numbers[i] > largest) {
                largest = numbers[i];
            } // end finding largest number 
        }
```

AND <= to <

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, numbers[counter]);
        }
```

Try catch block will simply handle your error in a graceful way . It won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, you can obtain an `IntStream` and get the [summary statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--).

```
final IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(numbers).summaryStatistics();
```

Answer (score 0):

As many people pointed out, you are using the values of your for-each loop as and index, meaning your code tries to access the position of whatever number your user inputs in your array.

So to fix it, you just need to do

```
smallest = i;
```

and

```
largest = i;
```